# How to add number in array in session in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create shop project with laravel 5.6.

I need save `product_id` in session.
I need craete array and save array in session.

**For example:**

`$cart = (2=>'100', 3=>'25', 4=>'100');`

Then after click other product, update array:

`$cart = (2=>'100', 3=>'25', 4=>'100', 6=>'100');`

I need after click on product button, run this function:

```
public function store(Request $request, $productId, $productSlug)
{
    if (session()->has('cart')) {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');
        if (in_array($productId, $cart)) {
            print "100";
        } else {
            $cart = array_push($cart, $productId);
        }
    } else {
        $cart = array($productId);
    }
    session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return session()->get('cart');
}
```

But after this function show this error: 
`in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given`

How to issue this problem?

Comment: This error means the `$cart` variable is not an array, so you can't use `$cart` as the second parameter of `in_array` function. You can try to dump the `$cart` variable after `$car = session()->get('cart')`;

Comment: try with return your `$cart` and make sure that your variable is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can read this document for shopping cart with laravel:

https://andremadarang.com/implementing-a-shopping-cart-in-laravel